eGARCH(1,1) model evaluation (R). How to assess model integrity?
I am using GARCH modelling for my bachelor thesis in Economics. I am entirely new to the concept, and have only been looking into these kind of models for about a week now. I am trying to do a comparison of volatility dynamics between Bitcoin, Ethereum, and the S&P 500. I was wondering if anybody could help me with the evaluation of output.
Right now I have settled on weekly log returns from Bitcoin of the last 6 years. I am using a eGARCH(1,1)-GED model, as I think that it suits my data the best. I have done a lot of iteration over different models/distributions. I also included a dummy variable for a specific date of a major global event to assess its effect on the data.
Given the p-values of 0 for the coefficients and the p-values of > 0.05 for the residuals tests' and the Goodness-of-Fit test, it looks good to me. Anyways, my question is - given my lack of experience - how do I further evaluate my model? When can I accept the model for further analysis and interpretation?
Thank you!
*          GARCH Model Fit        *
*---------------------------------*

Conditional Variance Dynamics   
-----------------------------------
GARCH Model : eGARCH(1,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(0,0,0)
Distribution    : ged 

Optimal Parameters
------------------------------------
        Estimate  Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)
mu      0.005174    0.000000 30818.655        0
mxreg1 -0.007587    0.000095   -79.822        0
omega  -0.195159    0.000346  -563.742        0
alpha1  0.026858    0.000067   398.347        0
beta1   0.956950    0.000686  1394.664        0
gamma1 -0.171288    0.000485  -353.122        0
vxreg1 -0.047483    0.000306  -155.024        0
shape   1.060467    0.002674   396.640        0

Robust Standard Errors:
        Estimate  Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)
mu      0.005174    0.000003 1940.4508 0.000000
mxreg1 -0.007587    0.000237  -32.0510 0.000000
omega  -0.195159    0.027368   -7.1310 0.000000
alpha1  0.026858    0.000505   53.1471 0.000000
beta1   0.956950    0.097386    9.8264 0.000000
gamma1 -0.171288    0.036241   -4.7263 0.000002
vxreg1 -0.047483    0.030302   -1.5670 0.117122
shape   1.060467    0.209286    5.0671 0.000000

LogLikelihood : 342.6141 

Information Criteria
------------------------------------
                    
Akaike       -2.1313
Bayes        -2.0358
Shibata      -2.1326
Hannan-Quinn -2.0931

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Residuals
------------------------------------
                        statistic p-value
Lag[1]                     0.8471  0.3574
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][2]    0.8474  0.5505
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][5]    2.0499  0.6067
d.o.f=0
H0 : No serial correlation

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Squared Residuals
------------------------------------
                        statistic p-value
Lag[1]                     0.1784  0.6727
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][5]    1.2104  0.8105
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][9]    2.9158  0.7728
d.o.f=2

Weighted ARCH LM Tests
------------------------------------
            Statistic Shape Scale P-Value
ARCH Lag[3]    0.1003 0.500 2.000  0.7515
ARCH Lag[5]    1.2961 1.440 1.667  0.6475
ARCH Lag[7]    2.1301 2.315 1.543  0.6898

Nyblom stability test
------------------------------------
Joint Statistic:  NaN
Individual Statistics:              
mu     0.03159
mxreg1 0.03045
omega  0.03250
alpha1 0.03266
beta1      NaN
gamma1 0.03008
vxreg1 0.03402
shape  0.03272

Asymptotic Critical Values (10% 5% 1%)
Joint Statistic:         1.89 2.11 2.59
Individual Statistic:    0.35 0.47 0.75

Sign Bias Test
------------------------------------


Adjusted Pearson Goodness-of-Fit Test:
------------------------------------
  group statistic p-value(g-1)
1    20     24.85       0.1654
2    30     34.92       0.2073
3    40     36.57       0.5811
4    50     54.15       0.2843


Elapsed time : 0.2744429


If you are interested in GARCH models, the site that discusses them the most is Cross Validated SE. See some relevant threads here. Quantitative Finance SE is also a good site for GARCH models but has a bit less volume.

Thank you @RichardHardy, I will take a look!
